# How do I disable automatic login in a debian live (standard) image?

Tags: debian

I'm [doing a big thing](https://serverfault.com/questions/1030016/), and I need to disable the automatic login on a debian live image.

I've copied the filesystem.squashfs from the [debian live standard](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-standard.iso) iso, and extraced it:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L
$ sudo mkdir squashfs-temp
$ cd squashfs-temp
$ sudo unsquashfs /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L/filesystem.squashfs
$ sudo chroot /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L/squashfs-temp/squashfs-root/
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L
$ sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /ISO/debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-standard.iso /mnt/loop
$ sudo cp -R /mnt/loop/* /images/os/debian/10.5L
$ sudo umount /mnt/loop
$ sudo cp /images/os/debian/10.5L/live/filesystem.squashfs /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L
$ cd /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L
$ sudo mkdir squashfs-temp
$ cd squashfs-temp
$ sudo unsquashfs /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L/filesystem.squashfs
$ sudo chroot /var/www/html/os/debian/10.5L/squashfs-temp/squashfs-root/
```

For my project to work, I need to disable automatic login and set an admin password. the problem is, I've looked at the usual locations:

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Neither appear to have the typical autologin settings. Additionally, this is the standard image, so there's no GUI, ergo no DM config files to edit (that I'm aware of/can find)... so where is the config that sets the image to automatically log in on boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option `live-config.noautologin` in a configuration file.

> Configuration files can be placed either in the root filesystem itself (`/etc/live/config.conf` and/or `/etc/live/config/*`), or on the live media (`live/config.conf` and/or `live/config/*`). If both places are used for a certain option, the ones from the live media take precedence over the ones from the root filesystem.

If you do use config files, you need to use the `boot=live` parameter.

Comment: I see /etc/live/ but it has some folders that are giving me pause... I have a `boot/` and `config.conf.d/` folders. I'm inclined to simply create the /etc/live/config.conf file as you suggest, but wanted to be sure I shouldn't do something like `/etc/live/config.conf.d/noautologin`

Comment: You can add the line `live-config.noautologin` into the file `live/config.conf` at the very bottom (or uncomment it if it's already in there) and add the `boot=live` parameter to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Giving it a shot now. the squashfs is compressing so it'll be a minute.
thanks for your help either way! BTW: the file did not exist, so I created it with that one line.

Comment: No problem. If my answer has helped, please do tick it as the answer.

Comment: done and done. that worked!